# Mule HTTP Request Config with OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, mule

I am experimenting with OAuth2 on HTTP request connector. It is throwing the below exception always:

```
SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":abstract-http-request-authentication-provider, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tcp":client-socket-properties, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls":context, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":raml-api-configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":proxy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http":ntlm-proxy}' is expected
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<http:request-config name="SF_Authorize_Configuration" protocol="HTTPS" host="${login.host}" basePath="${oauth2.url}" port="80" doc:name="Authorize Configuration" >
    <oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type clientId="my_client_id" clientSecret="my_client_secret" redirectionUrl="http://localhost:8081/oauth2callback">
        <oauth2:authorization-request authorizationUrl="https://my.api.com/services/oauth2/authorize" localAuthorizationUrl="http://localhost:8082/authorization" scopes="access_user_details, read_user_files">
        </oauth2:authorization-request>
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="https://my.api.com/services/oauth2/token"/>
    </oauth2:authorization-code-grant-type>
</http:request-config>
```

Answer (score -1):

This means that you have not provided the xml namespace for the xml tag.

If you have not used the UI to create this then please create using the design and then you can copy and paste your specific tag later by replacing it.

Edited answer,

It was similar for me for API kit. I re installed the Studio(Unzipped it again). This might work .

Comment: I was in the perspective that you might have copied the code from documentation and tried it . It is usual. Let me know if the new answer I provided Is working . Else I will move my answer to comments section.

Comment: I did install latest version of Anypoint studio after that, but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same issue. It was resolved by adding oauth2 namespace at the start mule tag, e.g.:

```
<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
...
xmlns:oauth2="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2"
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2 
...
>
```